# Trouble reading avro files in Jupyter notebook using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, spark-avro

I am trying to read an avro file in Jupyter notebook using pyspark. When I read the file i am getting an error.

I have downloaded spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0.jar, i am not sure where in my code I should be inserting the avro package. Any suggestions would be great.

This is an example of the code I am using to read the avro file

```
df_avro_example = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("example_file.avro")
```

This is the error I get

> AnalysisException: 'Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.avro. Please find an Avro package at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the jar to a location and use the following code snippet in your pyspark app

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars /path/tojar/spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0.jar pyspark-shell'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this, your advice work!!

Comment: I have run into a bit of trouble with my dates and was wondering what I need to do to correct the issue. I used the below example to pull data for last day of April, the whole month of May and the first day in June. But I am now looking to pull data for last day of December, the whole month of January and the first day in Feb. But because December is 2018 I am not sure how to adjust my code. Any suggestions @Ranga Vure

example_file.avro/20190{430,5,601}*\")